# Getting message as Hyper-V has not been installed

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v

I'm new to using virtual machines. I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise OS. I have enabled Hyper-v in my machine. When i run the Hyper-v manager and tried to connect my local machine, it shown message as follows

[image: I got this window]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V isn't available on Windows 7 client SKUs, like Enterprise.  It's only available on Windows Server 2008 x64 (some SKUs), Windows Server 2008 R2 (most SKUs), Windows 8 Professional x64, Windows 8 Enterprise x64, and Windows Server 2012 (again, most SKUs).

You've just installed the management tools which allow you to manage a remote instance of Hyper-V.